# What is purpose of engine pylon airfoils on the Hondajet HA-420?

Tags: jet-engine, drag, stability, engine-pylon

The engine pylons on the Hondajet are aerodynamically shaped so as to provide a lift force laterally and outwardly.

[image]
[Engine pylon as viewed from rear](https://www.flyhpa.com/files/2016/05/2016.05.28-09.33-flyhpa-574a0eae5a0bd-600x989.jpg)

[image]
[Engine pylon as viewed from front](http://www.hondajet.com/images/promos/otw-engine-placement.jpg)

Are these for lateral stability or drag reduction or both or other purposes?

Comment: seems like it tries to maintain a constant cross section area between the engine and aft fuselage. it's not meant to produce any force.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty interesting [write up on the pylon design here.](https://www.hondajet.com/Content/pdf/tech_papers/NC_vol%202_CS4_HondaJet_Kym15May.pdf) According to that the shape was chosen for a number of reasons including flutter reduction, stall characteristics and wave drag reduction. There is also some [more info here](http://icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2004/PAPERS/582.PDF) that briefly touches on the design.

Comment: The pylon writeup and all they looked at is quite interesting reading. Cabin size, wing laminar flow, stall characteristics, flutter, etc.  Too bad I can't unbolt the wing on my Cardinal, pull the engine, and replace them with a wing with 2 small jet engines!

Comment: @CrossRoads I think it would become an experimental but you could...

Comment: Yeah, that and the cost are a pretty big disincentive :) Plus my home field does not have jet fuel, only 100LL.

Comment: @CrossRoads: Most (possibly all) jet engines can run on 100LL, they just need to be inspected and maintained more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to confirm but in conventional aircraft design the engines are usually in front of and below the main wing. Firstly this would allow a maximum of the fuselage to be utilized for cabin space. Also, having such highly isolated engine nacelles would provide low wave drag coefficients allowing for smooth and efficient flying at higher Mach numbers. The engine is quite large for the aircraft and because mounting engines aft on a small plane, and because it is too low to mount below the wing, it is probable that it was the only location to place the engine without making considerable compromises otherwise.

[Edit] Running a CAD model of the Hondajet through a flow sim, the upward pylons should also provide extra yaw moment stability.

Comment: Functioning as strakes?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.